# hellp with data in json date not filling control angularjs

Tags: angularjs

in my angular js application I am retrieving data from the server serializing into json string and having them fill their respective html controls. All is working EXCEPT date. I am tearing my hair out. does anyone know how to handle this?
the json element looks like this

"  "PERSON.DOB":"1948-04-25T00:00:00","

and the html is a basic date control :

iF i remove the time stamp it will feed into the control. how do i handle this?
thanks in advance

I have created a simple plunk to describe the problem :http://plnkr.co/edit/BLtOPA
also, what is meant by adding a 'Z' to the end of the string what does this do?

Comment: Adding a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) may help get a quicker answer as we have no idea what your code looks like.

Comment: +1 We do need your code to help you. How do you parse this date? Could you try to modify the date in your json by adding a 'Z' at the end (just an idea...): `"1948-04-25T00:00:00Z"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem:

The RFC 3339/ISO 8601 "wire format" for date input is: YYYY-MM-DD. According to the HTML5 (working draft) specification, this is the format that must be used for the input's value. Your server is sending the date in ISO format.

#### Possible Solutions:

The easiest solution is iterate through all the dates in your JSON response, and convert them to a new date format using angular's built-in date filter.

Or more preferably, you can use a directive (not mine):

```
app.directive('dateInput', function(dateFilter) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        template: '<input type="date"></input>',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function (modelValue) {
                return dateFilter(modelValue, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
            });

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
                return new Date(viewValue);
            });
        },
    };
});
```

And your input will become:

```
<input class ="form-control" type='date' min='1900-01-01' max="2015-12-31" ng-model="person.DOB" date-input >
```

Here is a working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/pBaavbN87MqNaLkHzEwW

#### EDIT:

If you want to display the date in the format you received from the server, just change `input type="datetime"`. You don't have to write the directive as explained above. The above directive is for displaying in `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

#### Links:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date 
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive 
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt

Comment: thank you @farahan - will this affect how the date is being sent for posting back to the database? thank you for your help :)

Comment: Yes, it will change the date format being sent to the server. See my edit if you want to display the date in original format and send back the same.